# Avoiding greyed-out rows in ArcGIS batch processing?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, batch, zonal-statistics

I'm using the batch processing ability in ArcMap 10.6.1 to run a ModelBuilder tool using Zonal Statistics As Table and Add Fields on a bunch of rasters. When I try to specify where to save the output tables, all but the top line of the batch is greyed out. This is frustrating because when I start filling out all the other fields of the batch, the rows are not greyed out, but by the time I finish they often are. I lose all the time I put into filling out all the fields for the whole batch, only to be able to run the tool for the first raster.

While I am using a tool from ModelBuilder, I have had this happen when batch processing the existing tools too, including Zonal Statistics as Table.

Does anyone know how this happens and is there a way to avoid it?

I do not see a pattern for what causes it to go grey versus keep working for all the rows.

[image]